# dplyr: specific summarise methods for certain columns, default for the rest

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to summarise a grouped dataframe. For certain columns I need a specific aggregate method, here below for example concatenating strings at `d`, for other columns I apply a default method (below `first`). I found a way to do this by separating the column with specific method into another dataframe. This is quite complicated, 5 lines of code, 3 groupings, and what if I have more columns like this, or some of them are type of double. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this? For example it would be perfect if we could pass `first` as a default method for `summarise_all` and specific methods for only certain columns. I've read the docs and concluded that is not possible.

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
    a = sort(rep(letters[1:4], 5)),
    b = rep(letters[6:7], 10),
    c = rnorm(20, 1000, 500),
    d = rep(c('h', 'h', 'i', 'h'), 5)
)

grp <- df %>% group_by(a, b, d) %>% summarise_all(first)
grp_d <- grp %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(d = paste(d, collapse = ""))
grp_d$d <- factor(grp_d$d)
grp_othercols <- grp %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise_all(first)
merged <- bind_cols(grp_othercols %>% select(-d),
                    as.data.frame(grp_d['d']))
```

Comment: The case when using `first` is simple: `df %>% 
    group_by(a, b) %>% 
    mutate(d = factor(paste(d, collapse = ""))) %>% 
    slice(1)`, but for others things are more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Axeman's comment, just one grouping:

```
df %>% group_by(a, b, d) %>% summarise_all(first) %>% 
  mutate(d = factor(paste(d, collapse = ""))) %>% 
  summarise_all(first)
```

Comment: The second `group_by` is unnecessary. Any `summarise` call will drop the last group (i.e. `d`).

Comment: Also note that this will work for `first`, but when doing other calculations such as taking the mean.

Comment: thanks Edwin, this looks nice! Axeman, then maybe `group_by(a, b) %>% mutate(d = factor(paste(d, collapse = ""))) %>% summarise_all(first)` is enough?

Answer (score 1):

We can also pass multiple function to `summarize_all` and then selecting only the columns we are interested in:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(a, b) %>% 
    arrange(a, b, d) %>%
    summarise_all(c('c', 'd'), funs(paste = paste(unique(.), collapse = ''), f = first)) %>% 
    select(-c_paste, -d_f)
```

Note the `arrange()` as we never group on `d`, it does not get sorted and `first` give slightly different results.

Comment: thanks, this is something like I imagined. but this code throws me an `Additional arguments should be named` error at line `summarise_all(...)`. and if I name arguments like `.cols = c('c', 'd'), .funs = funs(...), ...)` it says `argument to 'first' does not match either 'default' or 'order_by'`.

Comment: Probably it's working only on the dev version of `dplyr` for now